# The buttons for awarding a bounty should be distinguishable from already awarded bounties in the mobile skin

Tags: bug, design, bounties, mobile-web, active-bounties

Whenever I see my currently active bounties from a mobile site, I feel as if they've already been awarded. This is how it looks from my chrome browser in Android:

[image]

The blue colour of the <kbd>+100</kbd> box is too dark: on the Desktop site this colour is used when the bounty is already awarded. A lighter tone should be used in mobile sites too, to denote active bounties.